# Алгоритм Эло: как вычисляется рейтинг?

Tags: алгоритм

Помогите разобраться, как вычисляется рейтинг игрока согласно алгоритму Эло??? Я сам чет запутался.

Согласно алгоритму, каждому игроку начисляется 400 очков. А дальше

```
Ea = 1 / 1 + 10(Rb - Ra)/400
Eb = 1 / 1 + 10(Ra - Rb)/400
```

Вот допустим 2 игрока. Выиграл первый. То как вычислить новый рейтинг первого игрока???

Comment: так а какие у них были рейтинги перед игрой ? 400 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3_%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%BE#%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0_%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%BE) не помогла?

Изначально у обоих по 400: `Ra = Rb = 400; Ea = Eb = 1/2`. Значит, как у новичков с рейтингом <2400, коэф. `K`, по версии ФИДЕ, у обоих 30.

Допустим, A победил и получает 1, B получает 0: `Sa=1, Sb=0`.

Новые рейтинги:

```
A: 400 + K * (Sa - Ea) = 400 + 30 * (1 - 0.5) = 415
B: 400 + 30 * (0 - 0.5) = 385
```

Comment: Ссылка нерабочая.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf спасибо, поправил.  Это древний вопрос, ещё с тех времён, когда это был HashCode ru  При переезде ссылка сломалась.